# Dropping server on pgadmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, database-server

Let's say you have added a postgres cluster on pgadmin4.

Does using delete/drop actually drop the cluster? or it just drops from pgadmin4? and nothing happens to the actual cluster.

I am a superuser, so definitely don't want to try it.

I always have to be very careful while disconnecting the server.

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's even possible to remotely drop a cluster. Either the service runs on a machine or it doesn't, but it doesn't manage itself.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the `Delete/Drop` option will remove the server from the PgAdmin4 Server tree, but does not delete/drop any data or databases

Comment: "Delete/Drop" is arguably the _worst_ choice in naming a "remove from list" option in a database management tool.

Comment: @RicardovandenBroek I couldn't agree more! haha

Comment: Update: It was renamed to "Remove Server"